# Unlock locked drive with Bitlocker using Password?

Tags: encryption, passwords, data-recovery, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I have a Bitlocker encrypted drive and when I encrypted the drive, I saved the Recovery Key to my USB. Then I changed my system windows from 8.1 to 7 (because of some reasons) and suddenly lost my USB.

Now, I have problem with unlocking the drive because I have no Recovery Key. but I still remember the Password I set to drive. Is there any method to unlock this encrypted drive with password instead of recovery key?

Note that I didn't save my recovery key to my Microsoft account.

Comment: No; it's not possible the recovery key is required;

Comment: But why? :( I have my password! so the ONLY way to unlock is having recovery key? It is senseless!

Comment: Security you were told to back it up...

Comment: And I backed up! but I lost that :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does BitLocker want a recovery key instead of a password?](https://superuser.com/questions/1014302/why-does-bitlocker-want-a-recovery-key-instead-of-a-password)

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is old (and still has no valid answer), this command asks for your password (not the recovery password) and unlocks your drive, if your drive has a password:

```
manage-bde -unlock drive: -pw
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference [BitLocker Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831507.aspx#BKMK_RecoveryInfo):

> **If I lose my recovery information, will the BitLocker-protected data be unrecoverable?**
>
> BitLocker is designed to make the encrypted drive unrecoverable
>   without the required authentication. **When in recovery mode, the user
>   needs the recovery password or recovery key to unlock the encrypted
>   drive.** Therefore, we highly recommend that you either store the
>   recovery information in AD DS, along with your Microsoft account
>   online, or another safe location.

See [Unlock a BitLocker-protected drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/unlock-bitlocker-protected-drive) for instuctions on unlocking the different kinds of drive (system, data, or removeable) using your password.

Reference http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/learn-more-about-bitlocker-drive-encryption:

> **Recovery options**
>
> To prevent losing access to BitLocker-protected drives in the event of
>   TPM failure, forgotten passwords, or loss of smart cards or USB keys,
>   it is important that you have a means for administrators to get access
>   to BitLocker drives. BitLocker supports the following methods to
>   recover access to protected drives:
>
> - Recovery key or recovery password. You can use a recovery key or a recovery password with BitLocker. If a BitLocker key is unavailable,
>     such as in the case of a missing smart card or forgotten user
>     password, a 48-digit recovery password can be used to unlock the
>     protected drive. In place of a password, a recovery key that has been
>     stored to a file on removable media, such as a USB flash drive, can
>     also be used to unlock the protected drive.
> - Backup of keys to Active Directory Domain Services. BitLocker recovery passwords can be stored in Active Directory Domain Services.
>     This allows administrators, such as help desk staff, to assist users
>     in recovering BitLocker-protected drives when they have forgotten or
>     misplaced their recovery password.
> - Data recovery agent. A data recovery agent is a designated person, such as a system administrator, who can use his or her administrative
>     credentials to unlock BitLocker-protected drives. BitLocker is not
>     configured with default data recovery agents, nor are data recovery
>     agents enabled by default. They must be enabled and configured by
>     using Group Policy.

Comment: But Ramhound (In my question's comments) says it's impossible! is "recovery password" refers to the password we set? and as I said, I changed my windows so all of keys are gone.

Comment: The recovery password is a 48 digit password. Is this the password you have?

Comment: No, I have only the password I set as an option in first page of bitlocker activation. like: "T!$isMy9ssword" for example.