# Is there any way to get BitLocker recovery key through normal password?

Tags: bitlocker

I had my External hard drive encrypted by BitLocker. I changed my OS and installed a new Windows without saving 48-digit. Now I have only my Password. Is there any way to access my data?

Comment: It explicitly tells you to save that data. Do you get a password prompt if you attach the drive? If no your data is lost without the recovery key. If your computer is domain joined it might be stored in the computer AD object.

Comment: If you didn't save the recovery key, and BitLocker requires the recovery key to access your data, then you are simply **out of luck** in the future follow the instructions and save the recovery key.  This comment is under the assumption that, it is asking for the recovery key, not the password when you connect to the drive to the computer and go to mount and access the volume

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does BitLocker want a recovery key instead of a password?](https://superuser.com/questions/1014302/why-does-bitlocker-want-a-recovery-key-instead-of-a-password)