# Can I stop BitLocker asking for a key on boot, without entering the recovery key?

Tags: bitlocker, tpm

We have a Windows 10 laptop belonging to a client which has started asking for a recovery key on boot:

> You need to enter your recovery key because Secure Boot policy has unexpectedly changed

I don't fully understand the relationship between Windows and the TPM, but I guess in some sense one has stopped trusting the other.

We're exploring the possibility of recovering the key from the client's Microsoft account, but assuming that doesn't work, I guess our last potential hope of recovering the data would be to get the laptop back into the usual state where it's happily unlocking itself on boot.

My main question is: is it possible to put the laptop back in a state that it unlocks itself, or is the laptop never going to be happy again until it gets the key?

Comment: Your data is encrypted, and without the recovery key, BitLocker cannot be disabled.  There is a reason the recovery key is being requested, likely an action was performed, this can be any number of different actions.  If this is a Windows 10 device, and if the account is connected to a Microsoft Account, it's possible the recovery key was backed up to your account.  If this is an Enterprise machine, it's possible the key was backed up to the domain controller, if neither of those things happen then the data is lost.

Comment: This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1014302/why-does-bitlocker-want-a-recovery-key-instead-of-a-password?rq=1) has an answer that lists a few reasons why the Recovery Key can be requested when using a TPM.